How close can we get to solving $\nu'\ast\mu=\mu\ast\nu$ for $\nu'$, where $\mu,\nu$ are probability measures on a group?
I've got an arbitrary finitely generated group $G$ with two probability measures, $\mu$ and $\nu$. Since $G$ is usually non-abelian, we have in general that $$
\mu\ast\nu \ne \nu\ast\mu
$$
I'm looking for ways to find approximate solutions to $$\tag{1}
\nu'\ast \mu = \mu \ast \nu
$$
for $\nu'$. Of course, $\nu'=\nu$ is an exact solution if $\nu$ commutes with $\mu$, which happens if one of them is supported on the center of $G$, or if $\nu$ is a linear combination of convolution powers of $\mu$, or some other trivial cases. But it isn't true in general.
In many cases, there is a convolutional inverse of $\mu$, i.e. a function $\mu^{-1}$ such that $$
\mu\ast\mu^{-1} = \mu^{-1}\ast\mu = \mathbb{1}_{e}
$$
where $e$ is the group identity. For example, if $\mu(e)>\frac12$, we have $||\mu-1_e||_1<1$ and thus $$
\mu^{-1} = \left(1_e - (1_e-\mu)\right)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (1_e-\mu)^{\ast n}
$$
is a convergent series that gives the inverse of $\mu$. When $\mu$ has a convolution inverse, then $\nu'=\mu\ast\nu\ast\mu^{-1}$ trivially solves (1). However, there's no reason to expect $\nu'$ to be a probability distribution in general. I believe that $\mu^{-1}$ is never a probability distribution unless $\mu$ is degenerate.

The question: How can we find the best approximate solution to (1), meaning, how can we find a probability measure $\nu'$ that minimizes $||\nu'\ast \mu - \mu\ast\nu||_1$?
My first thought as a starting place would be to write $\mu\ast\nu\ast\mu^{-1}$ as $\zeta^+-\zeta^-$ for positive measures $\zeta^\pm$ and then try $\nu'=\frac1{||\zeta^+||_1}\zeta^+$, but that's just a hunch and I have no clue to tell how close that is to minimizing $||\nu'\ast \mu - \mu\ast\nu||_1$.

Update: In some very restrictive cases, namely where $\mu$ is very close to being the identity and $\nu$ satisfies some strict regularity conditions on its decay rate, I can show that $\mu\ast\nu\ast\mu^{-1}$ is a probability distribution, even though we may not have $\mu\ast\nu=\nu\ast \mu$.

Measure should be defined by its Fourier coefficients (assuming the group has complete set of characters) and in this case we would get that  Fourier coefficients of the left must be the same as on the right when proper coefficients of $u$ are not zero.
